# window.print html with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, printing

How to use window.print html with ajax?

in my success callback

```
,
success(data){

//how to print the html in a new page?
}
```

I tried

```
var invoice = window.open(data, '_blank');
setTimeout(invoice.print(), 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout`  takes an unexecuted  function *(without parentheses)* or an Anonymous function. I would do this instead anyways:

```
var invoice = open(data);
invoice.onload = function(){
  this.print();
}
```

Comment: Note that `window` is implicit in the current `window`.

Comment: open is what? why use open instead of window.open?

Comment: Almost everything is a property of `window`. You don't type `window.document`, do you? Yes, that's the same as `window.open`.

Comment: so why some coder still type the window like window.print?

Comment: They don't know, or like to see it.